# Topbar reputation, votes cast, revisions and favorites user's summary seems to down to zero

Tags: bug, reputation, activity-summary

Today I notice that even if all the statistics works well and updates correctly for me and other, user stats in the top bar were all down to 'zero'.

A picture will describe better the problem than words :

[image: Strange bug with 'zero' stats]

This is not correct, as you can see in my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/954777). Do you guys experiment the same or is it because stats have been initialized at the beginning of the month (and week). I've never noticed this before, however, maybe I've looked bad...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both a new week *and* a new month started this Sunday, and your last points were made last Thursday, the 29th of August. Presumably you haven't voted since before Sunday either, nor have any of your favourites seen activity or any of your posts been editing since before that day either.

The summaries are *entirely* correct.

A new week is started every Sunday, and a new month every 1st day of the month at 00:00 UTC. The week and month stats do not cover the past 7 and 30 days respectively, instead they follow the calendar definition of a week and month.